# I cant debug on my Iphone once I have changed my Xamarin.Forms project´s code

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to debug my Xamarin Forms project on my physical IOS device (iPhone 7) using visual studio for mac, It works fine the first time, but once I change my code and debug on an emulator I can no longer debug on my physical device; I don't have this problem when I change my code and debug again as long as I am debugging in my iPhone the first time.

Once this happens I get the following errors:

Error 1: Failed to codesign 'bin/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone9.3-14.4/ProjectName.iOS.app': FullPath/ProjectName/ProjectName.iOS/bin/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone9.3-14.4/ProjectName.iOS.app: resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed

Error 2: /usr/bin/codesign exited with code 1

To debug again in my iPhone I have to remove my app from it, and remove my XCode project and create a new one for the provisioning profile.

Does anyone know how to solve this? I have looked for an answer on several sites, but no luck for me...
If you need more information I will provide it as soon as I see your request, thank you all for your time.

Comment: Make sure that the version of VS and Xcode are up to date . If the issue still exists ,  you could post the issue to **VS->Help->SendFeedback->Report a problem**  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I already solve it.

**Solution:**
Navigate to your projects root directory (FullPath/ProjectName/ProjectName.iOS/bin/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone9.3-14.4) from within your terminal then execute this command:
xattr -cr .

I have to do this every time I get the error

Comment: I don't have the `device-builds` folder after `Debug`. I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @TheHunterShergill Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding the app?

Comment: Yes, I have tried cleaning and rebuilding still got the same error. But after deleting all certificates I changed provisioning to Automatic then it went away. Now I am getting `No iOS signing identities match the specific provisioning profile 'VS: WildCard Development'`